# perl regex omit text between brackets but keep decimal after keyword

Tags: regex, string, perl, string-matching

I am stuck with getting a regular expression to work,
I have the string

```
my $str = "(1:[&a={1sa},s=3,keyword=0.1,qwsz={a}]:0.1)[s=2;p]:2:[s=3, keyword=9.23]";
```

and want to discard anything between the square brackets except for a decimal number which occurs after the substring `keyword=`. The resulting string should look like this:

```
"(1:0.1):2:9.23"
```

I tried to use the pattern `\[.+?keyword=([0-9]+\.[0-9]+).+?]` which matches what I don't want, I tested that in an online regex tester. But

```
my $str =~ s/\[.+?keyword=([0-9]+\.[0-9]+).+?]//g;
```

does not really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's only one `keyword` for each square bracket group, you can use

```
$str =~ s/\[[^]]*?keyword=([0-9.]+)[^]]*]|\[[^]]*]/$1/g;
```

See a [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/nP0vR4).

**Explanation**

We want to match all the `[...]` and replace them with the content of the capturing group, which is not empty only if there's a `keyword` inside the brackets:

```
  \[                 # first case: the [...] contains keyword. We match `[`
  [^]]*?             # followed by anything except a `]`, until the first...
  keyword=([0-9.]+)  # ... keyword pattern. We capture the wanted number
  [^]]*]             # and we match the rest of the [...] pattern.
|                    # OR
  \[[^]]*]           # second case: there's no keyword. We match, but 
                     # don't capture anything.
```

Answer (score 2):

This works using an executable replacement string. All sequences like `[...]` are replaced by either the value after `keyword` if it appears in the sequence, or the empty string if it does not.

```
use strict;
use warings;
my $str = '(1:[&a={1sa},s=3,keyword=0.1,qwsz={a}]:0.1)[s=2;p]:2:[s=3, keyword=9.23]';

$str =~ s{ \[ ( [^[\]]* ) \] }{
  $1 =~ /keyword=([\d.]+)/ ? $1 : '';
}egx;

print $str;
```

**output**

```
(1:0.1:0.1):2:9.23
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the below regex selection with empty string

```
\[((?!\])(?<!keyword=).)*(\]|(?=\d+\.\d+))|,.*?\]|\]
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[((?!\])(?<!keyword=).)*(\]|(?=\d+\.\d+)) // Starts with a [, not followed by ], not preceded by keyword=, including all characters till a ] or decimals are encountered
|,.*?\]                                    // OR a comma followed by anything till the first occurance of a ]
|\]                                        // OR a ]
```

eg.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $str = "(1:[&a={1sa},s=3,keyword=0.1,qwsz={a}]:0.1)[s=2;p]:2:[s=3, keyword=9.23]";
$str =~ s/\[((?!\])(?<!keyword=).)*(\]|(?=\d+\.\d+))|,.*?\]|\]//g;
print "$str";
```

Output

```
(1:0.1:0.1):2:9.23
```